# how to limit a logarithmic axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a curve with the following command but I need to limit the y-axis until 100, so can anybody help me find out how to do it?
Thanks in advance

```
ggplot(file1, aes(x=f11,colour=time, alpha=time, size=time))+
  geom_line(aes(y = S1))+scale_color_manual(values =c("t1"="red","t2"="magenta","t3"="coral4","t5"=cl[8]),
                     labels=labels1 ,name="Time")+
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1, 1, 1, 1),labels=labels1)+
  scale_size_manual(values = c(.6, .61, .61, .61),labels=labels1)+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title=title),
         alpha = guide_legend(title=title),
         size = guide_legend(title=title))+
  labs(title="Column 1")+ theme_bw()+theme(plot.title=element_text(size=12,hjust=0.5,face="bold"))+ 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  xlab( growth)+ylab(nutrient )+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 0.5, by=0.10), limits=c(0,0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `scale_y_log10` and set `limits` like in the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df,aes(x = x, y =y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,100))
```

Output:

[image]

#### Data

```
 df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = seq(1,150,length.out = 10))
```

Comment: My personal preference is to use `coord_cartesian()` rather than `scale_x_yyyy(limits=zzzz)` to define the extent of axes.  This is because `scale_x_yyyy` first filters the data and then applies imputation, which *may* lead to undesirable and misleading side effects.  `coord_cartesian()`, in contrast, first performs any impuation on the whole data frame and then "zooms" the plot to the requested area.  Here, since there is no imputation, the difference is moot.  But I'd still prefer `coord_cartesian()` as it is a good habit - it will always do what you expect.